# Python xml: parse attributes

Tags: python, xml

I have a newspaper in xml format and I am trying to parse specific parts.

My XML looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<articles>
   <text>
      <text.cr>
         <pg pgref="1" clipref="1" pos="0,0,2275,3149"/>
         <p type="none">
            <wd pos="0,0,0,0"/>
         </p>
      </text.cr>
      <text.cr>
         <pg pgref="1" clipref="2" pos="0,0,2275,3149"/>
         <p type="none">
            <wd pos="0,0,0,0"/>
         </p>
      </text.cr>
      <text.cr>
         <pg pgref="1" clipref="3" pos="4,32,1078,454"/>
         <p type="none">
            <wd pos="4,32,1078,324">The</wd>
            <wd pos="12,234,1078,450">Newspaper</wd>
         </p>
      </text.cr>
```

I want to parse "The" and "Newspaper" amongst others.
I used `xml.etree.ElementTree` and my code looks like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

for each_file in entries:
                                               
                        mytree = ET.parse(path.xml)
                        tree = mytree.findall('text')
                        

                        for x in tree:
                            x_ = x.findall('wd')
```

I managed to parse the root and also the attributes, but I don't know how to address `'wd'`
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Change your loop to

```
for x in tree:
  x_ = x.findall('.//wd')
  for t in x_:
      if t.text is not None:
          print(t.text)
```

Output:

```
The
Newspaper
```

Answer (score 0):

Below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<articles>
   <text>
      <text.cr>
         <pg pgref="1" clipref="1" pos="0,0,2275,3149"/>
         <p type="none">
            <wd pos="0,0,0,0"/>
         </p>
      </text.cr>
      <text.cr>
         <pg pgref="1" clipref="2" pos="0,0,2275,3149"/>
         <p type="none">
            <wd pos="0,0,0,0"/>
         </p>
      </text.cr>
      <text.cr>
         <pg pgref="1" clipref="3" pos="4,32,1078,454"/>
         <p type="none">
            <wd pos="4,32,1078,324">The</wd>
            <wd pos="12,234,1078,450">Newspaper</wd>
         </p>
      </text.cr></text></articles>'''

values = ['The', 'Newspaper']
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
wds = [wd for wd in root.findall('.//wd') if wd.text in values]
for wd in wds:
    print(wd.attrib['pos'])
```

output

```
4,32,1078,324
12,234,1078,450
```